# Trying to setup multiple stores or websites on single domain, magento 1.7

Tags: magento, web, subdomain

i would like to setup multiple stores or websites that each store will have its unique items and checkout seperate from others.

is there a new method for doing this .. i watched many tutorials and articles about this but it was written long time ago and most of was for multiple domains.

i can use subdomains and subdirectory structure.

but know that i am currently on shared godaddy hosting account with no virtual private dedicated server and thats important because i read that if this is the case maybe i can not have multiple stores from first place.

i am using magento ver 1.7

example:
store
www.store.com

store1
store1.store.com

store2
store2.store.com

store, store1 and store 2 has different items and checkouts but on single domain

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can setup subdomains on your hosting account with Go Daddy.  The main domain and each subdomain can have different content, such as a Magento store.  Magento can run on Go Daddy's Linux shared hosting; however, we do warn that shared hosting will not give optimal user experience for Magento.  We recommend a virtual dedicated or dedicated server.

Comment: Mike do you want me to create a seperate magento installation under each subdomain to act like a store!! this is what i got from your words .. if this is what u meant of course thats not what i want because the point is that all stores be connected to one admin backend to manage them.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a little confused.  Do you not want store, store1, and store2 to be different stores?  Can you clarify exactly what end result you want to achieve as I am not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to take advantage of magento multistore capability and do multiple stores A B and C under the same Domain name, but of course Store A, B and C will be controlled by only one admin backend of one magento installation and not multiple!!

Comment: Okay.  It looks like in that case you will just setup store.com, store1.store.com and store2.store.com to all use the same folder for their content and you just have the .htaccess redirect people to the right content for each store. I am sorry I misunderstood your question initially.